# How to combine two files in osx kernel extension using vn_rdwr() API

Tags: c++, c, macos, kernel

I have two file test1 and test2 each of size 2 gb. I want to combine these two file into one virtual file of size 4 gb in kernel space. Using kernel extension. I went though the API vn_rdwr(). But it is taking const char * as file path . But how I will give two file vnodes names and combine them into a virtual file. Individual files are exist, but I need combine them into a virtual file of 4 gb size.. Any API suggestion?. I do ot want to use any user space library or command.

Comment: Please add at least a snipped code

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of this exercise? It is highly unlikely you have a legitimate reason to do it. I don't know OS X specifically, but it should be clear this kind of hackery is not going to fly. You would need to hack the vfs layer which is a solid no-no. Alternatively, you may try to get away without a total hackery in the form of a device file which redirects i/o appropriately or a dedicated fuse filesystem. But as noted earlier, it sounds like you are trying to do something wrong.

Comment: But I tried with FUSE driver also. But not able to combine two files into one.